# Is it possible to add members to Aeron Cluster w/o reconfiguring existing ones?

Tags: distributed-system, raft, aeron

I'm looking for a way to add **new members** to existing Aeron cluster **without reconfiguring existing ones**.

It seems cluster members are defined [statically during startup](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Cluster-Tutorial#424-consensus-module)  as described in the Cluster Tutorial:

```java
final ConsensusModule.Context consensusModuleContext = new ConsensusModule.Context()
    .errorHandler(errorHandler("Consensus Module"))
    .clusterMemberId(nodeId)                                                                    
    .clusterMembers(clusterMembers(Arrays.asList(hostnames))) // <------ HERE                   
    .clusterDir(new File(baseDir, "consensus-module"))                                          
    .ingressChannel("aeron:udp?term-length=64k")                                                
    .logChannel(logControlChannel(nodeId, hostname, LOG_CONTROL_PORT_OFFSET))                    
    .replicationChannel(logReplicationChannel(hostname))                                         
    .archiveContext(aeronArchiveContext.clone());
```

If I understand this correctly, if I want to add more nodes, I need to reconfigure each existing node to include the new member.

Moreover, I found this in [Aeron Cookbook](https://aeroncookbook.com/distributed-systems-basics/consensus-algorithms/#raft) (emphasis mine)

> Key aspects of Raft:
>
> - there is a Strong Leader, which means that all log entries flow from the leader to followers
> - Raft makes use of randomized timers to elect leaders. This adds a few milliseconds to failover, but reduces the time to agree an elected leader (in Aeron Cluster, this is a maximum of the election timeout * 2).
> - the Raft protocol allows runtime configuration changes (i.e. adding new or removing nodes at runtime). **At the time of writing, this feature is still pending in Aeron Cluster.**

However, I do see classes like `io.aeron.cluster.DynamicJoin` and its usage in `io.aeron.cluster.ConsensusModuleAgent` which makes me think that adding nodes dynamically is possible and perhaps the cookbook is outdated.

Do you know a way to join more nodes without touching existing ones?

Comment: Looking at the [io.aeron.cluster.DynamicMembershipTest#shouldDynamicallyJoinClusterOfThreeNoSnapshots](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/blob/c6985c882eb227e0f1b4684dfb30119a00fa87dc/aeron-system-tests/src/test/java/io/aeron/cluster/DynamicMembershipTest.java#L67) - it seems promising that it is possible. I just need to comprehend the test harness code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible!** The context should be built like this:

```java
ConsensusModule.Context()
    .errorHandler(errorHandler("Consensus Module"))
    .clusterMemberId(Aeron.NULL_VALUE) // <1>
    .clusterMembers("") // <2>
    .memberEndpoints(memberEndpoints(hostnames[nodeId], nodeId)) // <3>
    .clusterConsensusEndpoints(consensusEndpoints(hostnames)) // <4>
    .clusterDir(File(baseDir, "consensus-module"))
    .ingressChannel("aeron:udp?term-length=64k")
    .logChannel("aeron:udp?term-length=64k")
    .replicationChannel(logReplicationChannel(hostname))
    .archiveContext(aeronArchiveContext.clone())
```

1. `clusterMemberId` must be set to `Aeron.NULL_VALUE`. The member ID will be generated automatically
2. `clusterMembers` should be empty. Static members are not required for a dynamic node
3. `memberEndpoints` is the channel configuration of this node. The format is `ingress:port,consensus:port,log:port,catchup:port,archive:port`. Very similar to [static `clusterMembers` configuration](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Cluster-Tutorial#424-consensus-module) for a single node but without member ID infront.
4. `clusterConsensusEndpoints` is the comma-separated list *consensus:port* channels of known cluster members. I think of it similar to "bootstrap" list of hosts to join.

Comment: A more comprehensive example is available here: [io.aeron.test.cluster.TestCluster#startDynamicNode](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/blob/3b9ec7a084d070de5b3f28b8434e40f465714664/aeron-test-support/src/main/java/io/aeron/test/cluster/TestCluster.java#L369-L392)